# Commenting System For A Website

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, ajax, comments

I hope this is the right place for such a question.
I am developing a website that has no users system.
I am looking for a commenting system for the website. 
Requirements:

- Ajax commenting
- Flagging comments
- administration (deleting comments)
- php using my DB or external service
- No registration, no FB comments
- Option for a captcha
- Hebrew or customizable interface

Can you please suggest such a system?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a system like [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). You can see a list of features [here](http://disqus.com/for-websites/), it seems to meet most of your criteria.

Comment: I'd second using Disqus, been using it for some time and it's a great system.

Comment: the problem with it is that you need a registration

Comment: ...and it requires 3rd party cookies to be enabled. I'm not sure what the default browser behaviour is regarding 3rd party cookies - to block or permit - but all my test browsers have blocked 3rd party cookies for such a long time that I've convinced myself it is the default behaviour in many browsers (this perhaps warrants another question)?! The only side effects I've come across with having 3rd party cookies disabled is that advertising (tracking) cookies aren't set (a good thing) and Disqus doesn't work!!

Comment: I guess the operative words in my answer would be "a system *like*" and "seems to meet *most* of your criteria". :-) I'm sure there are similar/alternative systems available, I just knew Disqus was one of the more popular ones, so thought it would be worth a mention.